# Spring Security, always redirect to Login page

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, weblogic11g

I have a serious problem...
i'm trying to create an application on weblogic 11g, with Spring 3, Hibernate 3 and AngularJS.
for 2 days, i was in deep difficulty to make my app working.
finally, i was able to make this work !

but, the problem is when i authenticate myself, and i navigate on the app, on each page, 
spring security redirect me on the login page... and i really don't know why...

**Web.xml :**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.bla.Init</listener-class>
</listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
      <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

**Spring.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Basic Configurations -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="test.model"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.repository"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.service"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.controller"/>

    <!-- SpringMVC -->
    <import resource="spring-mvc.xml"/>

    <!-- SpringData -->
    <import resource="spring-jpa.xml"/>

    <!-- SpringSecurity -->
    <import resource="spring-security.xml"/>
</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml** :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/login?error=403">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=403" default-target-url="/protected/home" />

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                    data-source-ref="myRapportDataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="select nni, password, enabled from system_user where nni = ?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="select u.nni as login, u.user_role as role from system_user u where u.nni = ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

i add the **spring-mvc.xml** too :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- Login Interceptor -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/protected/**"/>
            <bean class="gram.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
        <!-- workaround to fix IE8 problem -->
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

at first, this app was on Tomcat 6 and worked fine, but i have to migrate it on weblogic 10.3.6

any ideas ? i'm almost despered...

thank you very much every one to take a look at my problem

Comment: Try `pattern="/**" access="permitAll"`.

Comment: My God sp00m, you saved me ! i was only that... thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

With

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
```

Only the URL matching `/` will have the `permitAll` access. So what you need is actually:

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```